# Getting specified records only for today sql

Tags: t-sql

In need to get specified records(where result is Pass and result is Fail) only for todays date. What would the best way be of doing this?

```
SELECT
    A.EmployeeNumber,
    A.Result,
    FROM AssessmentData A
WHERE A.Result = 'PASS' OR A.Result = 'FAIL' AND A.TrainingStartDate = GETDATE()
```

The above is not quite there yet

kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT
    A.EmployeeNumber,
    A.Result
FROM AssessmentData A
WHERE A.Result IN ('PASS','FAIL') 
      AND A.TrainingStartDate >= dateadd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)
      And A.TrainingStartDate < dateadd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 1)
```

There are a couple problems here.  GetDate() returns date AND time, so... unless the training start date matched current date and time down to the millisecond, you would not get your data.

Also, be careful when mixing AND with OR in the where clause.  Order of operations is important so you should always use parenthesis.  Notice that I changed your condition to an IN condition.  This following query is equivalent to the one I already posted.

```
SELECT
    A.EmployeeNumber,
    A.Result
FROM AssessmentData A
WHERE (A.Result = 'PASS' or A.Result = 'FAIL')
      AND A.TrainingStartDate >= dateadd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0)
      And A.TrainingStartDate < dateadd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()), 1)
```

Take note of the parenthesis in the above code.  It forces the OR'd condition to be evaluated separately from the other AND conditions.